# Can I share informations from USA company register?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, business, companies

I want to start my own directory website. Can I use informations from [SEC.gov | Company Search Page](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) and add to my website? Is it legal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most certainly is legal, although I don't see anything directly on the site regarding the specific search data. Most federal data (content for that matter) are automatically open when published by law. [SEC's Open Gov Commitment (which actually seems like they stopped trying mid Obama's first term)](https://www.sec.gov/open) doesn't name that dataset specifically, but would be safe to assume if the SEC is publishing it, it is fair game.